# how do i insert selected option into database from givn 4-5 options by using spinner?

Tags: android, mysql

I am developing an app where on some page user need to select one option from given 4-5 options currently I'm using spinner for this functionality now the question is, if user selects 3rd or 4th option(only single option selection permitted) select how do i insert that particular option in mysql php database.following is the code I'm using right now..

```
//MainActivity.java

    public class MainActivity_D extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{

            //Declaring an Spinner
            private Spinner spinner2, spinner1;
            private String str_spinner1, str_spinner2, s_name, s_course;
            //An ArrayList for Spinner Items

            private ArrayList<String> students1;
            private ArrayList<String> students2;

            Button mBtnSave;

            //JSON Array

            private JSONArray result1, result2, result;

            //TextViews to display details
            private TextView textViewName1;
            private TextView textViewName2;
            private TextView textViewCourse;
            private TextView textViewSession;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.mainactivity_d);

                //Initializing the ArrayList
                students1 = new ArrayList<String>();
                students2 = new ArrayList<String>();

                //Initializing Spinner


                //Adding an Item Selected Listener to our Spinner
                //As we have implemented the class Spinner.OnItemSelectedListener to this class iteself we are passing this to setOnItemSelectedListener


                spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
                spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

                spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
                spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

                mBtnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

                mBtnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        submitForm();

                    }
                });

                //Initializing TextViews
                textViewName1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewName1);
                textViewName2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewName2);
                //      textViewCourse = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewCourse);
                //      textViewSession = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewSession);

                //This method will fetch the data from the URL
                getData1();
                getData2();

            }

            private void submitForm() {
                // Submit your form here. your form is valid
                //Toast.makeText(this, "Submitting form...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            //    s_name = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();
            //    s_course = spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString();

                Toast.makeText(this, "Signing up...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                new InsertActivity(this).execute(s_name, s_course);


            }

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


                switch (parent.getId()){

                    case R.id.spinner1:
                        spinner1.setSelection(position);
                        s_name = (String) spinner1.getSelectedItem();
                        //    getData1();
                        // showToast("Spinner1: position=" + position);

                        break;


                    case R.id.spinner2:
                        spinner2.setSelection(position);
                        s_course = (String) spinner2.getSelectedItem();
                        //    getData2();
                        break;
                }

            /*if(spinner1.getId()==R.id.spinner1) {
                  textViewName1.setText(getName(position));
                }
                else if(spinner2.getId()==R.id.spinner2)
                {
                    textViewName2.setText(getCourse(position));
                }
                switch (parent.getId()){

                    case R.id.spinner1:
                        //    getData1();
                        // showToast("Spinner1: position=" + position);

                        break;


                    case R.id.spinner2:
                        //    getData2();
                        break;
                }*/
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {


            }


         /*   private String getName(int position){
                String name="";
                try {
                    //Getting object of given index
                    JSONObject json = result.getJSONObject(position);

                    //Fetching name from that object
                    name = json.getString(Config.TAG_NAME);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                //Returning the name
                return name;
            }
            private String getCourse(int position){
                String course="";
                try {
                    JSONObject json = result.getJSONObject(position);
                    course = json.getString(Config.TAG_COURSE);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return course;
            }*/

            private void getData1() {
                //Creating a string request
                StringRequest stringRequest1 = new StringRequest(Config.DATA_URL1,
                        new Response.Listener<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String response1) {
                                JSONObject j1 = null;
                                try {
                                    //Parsing the fetched Json String to JSON Object
                                    j1 = new JSONObject(response1);

                                    //Storing the Array of JSON String to our JSON Array
                                    result1 = j1.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY1);

                                    //Calling method getStudents to get the students from the JSON Array
                                    getStudents1(result1);
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error1) {

                            }
                        });

                //Creating a request queue
                RequestQueue requestQueue1 = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

                //Adding request to the queue
                requestQueue1.add(stringRequest1);
            }

            private void getStudents1(JSONArray j1) {
                //Traversing through all the items in the json array
                for (int i = 0; i < j1.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        //Getting json object
                        JSONObject json1 = j1.getJSONObject(i);

                        //Adding the name of the student to array list
                        students1.add(json1.getString(Config.TAG_COURSE));
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                //Setting adapter to show the items in the spinner
                spinner1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity_D.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, students1));
            }

        //Initializing TextViews

        //      textViewCourse = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewCourse);
        //      textViewSession = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewSession);

        //This method will fetch the data from the URL

            private void getData2() {
                //Creating a string request
                StringRequest stringRequest2 = new StringRequest(Config.DATA_URL2,
                        new Response.Listener<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String response2) {
                                JSONObject j2 = null;
                                try {
                                    //Parsing the fetched Json String to JSON Object
                                    j2 = new JSONObject(response2);

                                    //Storing the Array of JSON String to our JSON Array
                                    result = j2.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY);

                                    //Calling method getStudents to get the students from the JSON Array
                                    getStudents2(result);
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error1) {

                            }
                        });

                //Creating a request queue
                RequestQueue requestQueue2 = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

                //Adding request to the queue
                requestQueue2.add(stringRequest2);
            }

            private void getStudents2(JSONArray j2) {
                //Traversing through all the items in the json array
                for (int i = 0; i < j2.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        //Getting json object
                        JSONObject json2 = j2.getJSONObject(i);

                        //Adding the name of the student to array list
                        students2.add(json2.getString(Config.TAG_USERNAME));
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                //Setting adapter to show the items in the spinner
                spinner2.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity_D.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, students2));
            }


        }

        //InsertActivity.java

        public class InsertActivity extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

            private Context context;
            Boolean error, success;

            public InsertActivity(Context context) {
                this.context = context;
            }

            protected void onPreExecute() {

            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
                String s_name = arg0[0];
                //  String userName = arg0[1];
                String s_course = arg0[1];

                String link;
                String data;
                BufferedReader bufferedReader;
                String result;

                try {
                    data = "?s_name=" + URLEncoder.encode(s_name, "UTF-8");
                    //    data += "&username=" + URLEncoder.encode(userName, "UTF-8");
                    data += "&s_course=" + URLEncoder.encode(s_course, "UTF-8");


                    link = "http://insert_s1.php" + data;

                    //   link = "http://example.com/mangoair10/tryrr.php" + data;

                    URL url = new URL(link);
                    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                    bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                    result = bufferedReader.readLine();
                    return result;

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
                    // return null;
                }

                return null;
            }

          /*  @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

                String jsonStr = result;
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                    String query_result = jsonObj.getString("success");
                    String message_result = jsonObj.getString("message");

                    if (query_result.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                        Toast.makeText(context,message_result , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    } else if (query_result.equalsIgnoreCase("-1")) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, message_result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }*/

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

                String jsonStr = result;

                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                    String query_result = jsonObj.getString("query_result");
                    Log.e("TAG", String.valueOf(query_result));

                    //   String message_result = jsonObj.getString("message");

                /*    if (query_result.equals("SUCCESS")) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Insert", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    } else if(query_result.equals("FAILURE")){
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Unable to Insert", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }*/

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }

        //Config.java

        public class Config {
            //JSON URL
         //   public static final String DATA_URL = "http://example.com/jsonphp1.php";
            public static final String DATA_URL1 = "http://example.com/jsonphp2.php";
            public static final String DATA_URL2 = "http://example.com/jsonphp1.php";

            //Tags used in the JSON String
            public static final String TAG_USERNAME = "username";
            public static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
            public static final String TAG_COURSE = "course";
            public static final String TAG_SESSION = "session";

            //JSON array name
            public static final String JSON_ARRAY = "result";
            public static final String JSON_ARRAY1 = "result1";
            public static final String JSON_ARRAY2 = "result2";


        }

//this is my php file
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('Unable to Connect'); 

$s_name=$_POST['s_name'];
$s_course=$_POST['s_course'];
Sid=$_GET['id'];

  $query = "UPDATE `students` SET s_name = '$s_name', s_course= '$s_course' WHERE id='$id'"; 

 $inserted = mysqli_query($con, $query);

// echo  $inserted;

 if($inserted) {
    echo '{"query_result":"SUCCESS"}';
}
else{
    echo '{"query_result":"FAILURE"}';
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Post your json response..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android)

Comment: 1000's of related post on SO. Did you try to search? Well, you can't parse an integer as an object.

Comment: But i also want to insert a spinner selected item into database,

Comment: In json response no any value shows

Answer (score 0):

The error is self explanatory. You are getting an Integer in your response which cannot be converted to a JSONObject. Log your response and check if it is a valid JSON.

Comment: I am doing Log.e("TAG", String.valueOf(query_result));

Answer (score 0):

In your asyntask onPostExecute method print response like this and post your    response then error will be detected

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            String jsonStr = result;

            Log.e("TAG",jsonStr );
        }
```

Comment: "java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message" this message shows in logcat

Comment: just add some string to that as  Log.e("TAG","response is: "+jsonStr );

Comment: I am doing this in logcat shows "http://example.in/Spinner/insert_s1.php?s_name=tt&s_course=ss" this values but when i clicked on url in browser shows no any data

Comment: I don't really understand that you are unable to parse result or unable to make a service call check your URL from API team once

Comment: i am unable to parse result

Comment: then please post your json response. I will help you to parse

Comment: If your service call is successful then you wont get NullPointerException while printing result json